# How to Bind Data to kendo grid by passing date from kendo datepicker?

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am new in Kendo UI, I have one kendo DatePicker and one Kendo GridView. After selecting a date from DatePicker according the data should bind to the Kendo GridView. I use jquery with Ajax and my jquery function is

[image: Click event]

```
List<MDA.AppEntities.Orders.OrderList> objConsults = new List<MDA.AppEntities.Orders.OrderList>(); 
objConsults = DataFacade.Operations.GetCustomerOrderDetailsByCustomerID(Patientid,startDate,en‌​dDate ); 
return new PrimeJsonResult { MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, Data = new GridModel<MDA.AppEntities.Orders.OrderList> { Data = objConsults } };
```

It is going inside `success: function(data)`, but not executing inside code and jump back to `$.ajax(`), and I don't understand why.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MDA.AppEntities.Orders.OrderList>(Model.OrderList)
    .Name("GridOrders")
    .PrefixUrlParameters(false)
    .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Bound(o => o.Ord_ID).Title("Event ID").Width("10%");
        col.Bound(o => o.Ord_Date).Title("Event Date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width("10%");
        col.Bound(o => o.Status).ClientTemplate("# if (EventType == 'eConsult') { # " + "<strong> #: EventConsultStatus #</strong> "
            + " # } else  if (OS_ID == " + (int)MDA.AppConstants.OrderStatus.AllOrderStatus.LocalPickupInScriptSureQueue + " || OS_ID == "
            + (int)MDA.AppConstants.OrderStatus.AllOrderStatus.LocalPickupProcessing + " || OS_ID == " + (int)MDA.AppConstants.OrderStatus.AllOrderStatus.LocalPickupPending
            + " || OS_ID  == " + (int)MDA.AppConstants.OrderStatus.AllOrderStatus.LocalPickupEnteredWithErrors + " || OS_ID  == "
            + (int)MDA.AppConstants.OrderStatus.AllOrderStatus.LocalPickupScriptSureTimeWait + "){ # " + " <p> Rx Approved </p> " + " # } else if (OS_ID == "
            + (int)MDA.AppConstants.OrderStatus.AllOrderStatus.LocalPickupEntered + " || OS_ID == " + (int)MDA.AppConstants.OrderStatus.AllOrderStatus.PickedFromLocalPharmacy
            + ") { # " + " <p> LPU Complete </p>" + " # } else { # " + "<strong> #: OS_Desc # </strong>" + " # }  #").Title("Status").Width("12%");
        col.Bound(o => o.Comment).Title("Details").Width("20%");
        col.Bound(o => o.TotalPrice).Title("Rx Cost").Format("$ " + "{0:F2}").Width("8%");
        col.Bound(o => o.EventConsultStatusID).ClientTemplate(" # if((OS_ID==" + (int)MDA.AppConstants.OrderStatus.AllOrderStatus.OrderSubmitted
            + "|| OS_ID ==" + (int)MDA.AppConstants.OrderStatus.AllOrderStatus.ConsultationStarted
            + ")&& (EventConsultStatusID==" + (int)MDA.AppConstants.ConstantValues.ConsultationStatus.SUBMIT
            + " || EventConsultStatusID==" + (int)MDA.AppConstants.ConstantValues.ConsultationStatus.START
            + "))  {# " + @Html.ActionLink(String.IsNullOrEmpty("EditConsultation") ? "-" : "EditConsultationlink", "CreateConsultation", new { @CustID = "#=Cust_ID#", @IsEdit = "#=Ord_ID#" }, getHtmlAttributesForActionLink("EditConsultation")) + "#} else if ( EventConsultStatusID == "
            + (int)MDA.AppConstants.ConstantValues.ConsultationStatus.WRITTEN + ") {# <a  href= " + Url.Action("ReviewConsultation", "Customer", new { id = "#=Ord_ID#" }) + " > view consult  <p>  See Doctor Notes and place Order if Prescription Written  </p> </a>  #}  else if (EventConsultStatusID == "
            + (int)MDA.AppConstants.ConstantValues.ConsultationStatus.PENDING + ") {#  <a  href=" + Url.Action("ReviewConsultation", "Customer", new { id = "#Ord_ID#" })
            + "> view consult  <p>  See Doctor Notes and Respond  </p>  </a> #}   else if (Eligible_ReFill && (OS_ID == 35 || OS_ID == 41)){ # <p> Eligible for Re-fill </p> <span > Please click on View Consult Link to see Refill link </span> #} else if (Eligible_ReOrder && (OS_ID == 35 || OS_ID == 41) && EventTypeID == 1) {# <p> Eligible for Re-Order  </p> <span > Please click on View Consult Link to see ReOrder link </span> #} else if (EventType == 'eConsult' || EventType == 'TeleConsult') {# <a  href="
            + Url.Action("ReviewConsultation", "Customer", new { id = "#=Ord_ID#" }) + "> view consult  </a> #} else  {# <a  href=" + Url.Action("OrderDetails", "Customer", new { id = "#=Ord_ID#" })
            + "> view consult  </a> # } if (OS_ID ==" + (int)MDA.AppConstants.OrderStatus.AllOrderStatus.OrderShipped + " || OS_ID == " + (int)MDA.AppConstants.OrderStatus.AllOrderStatus.PickedFromLocalPharmacy + ") {#  <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=javascript:CenterWindow(900,800,50,"
            + Url.Action("ViewReceipt", "Customer", new { id = "#=Ord_ID#" }) + ">);> View/Print Receipt </a> #} if (OS_ID != " + (int)MDA.AppConstants.OrderStatus.AllOrderStatus.OrderCanceled + ") {# <br /> <a  href="
            + Url.Action("AttachReporToConsult", "Customer", new { OrderId = "#=Ord_ID#" }) + "> Attach Report </a> #} #").Title("Sample1").Width("25%");
    })
    .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
    .Pageable(Page => Page.Refresh(true).PageSizes(true).PreviousNext(true))
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("_DemoDashBoard", "Customer", new { patientid = Model.CustomerID, startdate= Model.SearchStartDate, enddate=Model.SearchEndDate }))
        .ServerOperation(false)
    )
)
```

Comment: Please post your grid code.

Comment: @Vash Action Result Method

List<MDA.AppEntities.Orders.OrderList> objConsults = new List<MDA.AppEntities.Orders.OrderList>(); 
objConsults = DataFacade.Operations.GetCustomerOrderDetailsByCustomerID(Patientid,startDate,endDate );
return new PrimeJsonResult

             {
                 MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue,
                 JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                 Data = new GridModel<MDA.AppEntities.Orders.OrderList>

                 {
                     Data = objConsults
                 }
             };

Comment: Please add new information to the question next time. :)

Comment: You have a grid in your view named `GridOrders`, please add the source code for that grid to your question. That makes it easier to debug your issue.

Comment: @Vash I added GridOrder View Code

Comment: Thanks, you deleted the old code though. :P

Comment: @Vash is this enough?

Comment: You also made it a bit hard on yourself by using screenshots. You can just copy/paste the code into your answer and use the "code sample" button to format the code into a code-block. :)

Comment: @Vash yes I added below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the ajax call. Try this, `dataSource.read()` should call your action with the updated parameters:

```
$("#showDate").click(function(){
    var pid = $("#PatientID").val();
    var dtStartDate = $("#startDate").val();
    var dtEndDate = $("#endDate").val();

    if(dtStartDate > dtEndDate) {
        $("#spnshowDate").html("<html>From date should not be greater than To date</html>");
    }

    var grid = $("#gridOrders").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.read({ patientid: pid, startdate: dtStartDate, enddate: dtEndDate })
});
```

Comment: what is the defect in My jquery function

Comment: Ok I'll try and let you know

Comment: I got my answer I used lots of JS files related to telerik and it conflict each other now I resolved it.